# Assign the same event for multiple components on windows forms designer

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, windows-forms-designer

My program's GUI has a table with a textbox in each cell. When the user types something on a cell I want my program to get that something, plus the row and column the cell occupies on the table.

Creating an event for each cell manually is a lot of work, and each event would do the same thing, so I was wondering if there's an easier way to do this?

Comment: use grid view, that would help

Comment: I used TableLayoutPanel to build the table, but I don't have much experience with windows forms so I'm not sure what you mean by grid view.

Comment: r u using visual c++ ?!

Comment: Yes, I am using C++

Comment: How many textbook do you have ?!

Comment: Textboxes? Around 80

Comment: You should really be more specific about the question, by the way table layout panels are not designed for such problems, though that you can find tricks to handle them by a lookup table and position of text boxes I don't think if it is a good idea to do that

Comment: Also, 90 textboxes in a table doesnt sound to have a good UI for client, send a picture of the form maybe there are better ways to do that

Comment: It's a sudoku program, it has a 9x9 table with 81 textboxes for the user to input the values, and the program needs to read the inputted value, the row and the column of the textbox to know whether the inputted value is legal.

Comment: So you should use datagridview, much easier

Comment: bur for sodoku i wouldn't use even a table, I think naming the button and using the name to decode how to get the changed cell would be easier

Answer (score 0):

You can use one event handler function for several events, in your case the problem is to determine who has raised the event.

It is important to mention that tablelayout panels don't actually have cells, where you could think of container of objects. Some tricks have mentioned [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/126882/How-can-I-know-the-clicked-cell-in-the-TableLayout) for how to detect clicked row and column of changed textboxes(this link provided example of buttons but it is the same for texboxes too) but I highly recommend to use [GridViews](http://www.functionx.com/vccli/controls/dgv.htm) instead.